# Can I get lower gas fees if I have no hurry?

Tags: gas

I need to make a transaction in the ethereum blockchain, i don't have too much ether and I want to get the lowest fee posible, i don't need it to be executed fast.

Is it safe/valid to lower the gas fee to, let's say, 34 GWEI and wait until some miner takes the transaction? or do I have to wait until gas fee is low to place the transaction manually?

Comment: the best time to send transactions is Saturday morning or Sunday morning NY time, like 6 oclock

Answer (score 1):

You can send your transaction whenever you want. When your gas is ideal for a miner, it will take and process your transaction. So you don't have to wait for low gas fees. There will be no a problem.

Comment: A low enough fee could cause the transaction to never be taken by a miner even if still room in the block

Comment: Yes, if it is too low It might be. The decision is Alejo's